# How to insert dateof(now()) in text format in cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I have a table that has a column in text format. I need to write an insert CQL like the following.

INSERT INTO checktable(prop_name, description, somevalue) VALUES
('ABC', 'XYZ', dateof(now()));

Here "somevalue" column is of text type but I need to insert the current date-time.

Comment: Krishna, better to achieve this through program.

Comment: Here's an answer where I've prettymuch done this, step-by-step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722515/how-to-convert-a-value-of-date-type-to-text-in-cassandra/63730961#63730961

Answer (score 0):

What you have described should be fixable by using a **User Defined Function (UDF)**. In fact you could have 2 **UDF**s, one for *date->text* and another for *text->date* (using your own custom format).

**UDF** body can be created in *Java* or *JavaScript*. (or *Python* for *Cassandra 3.x*)

**Example:**  you can see the example of UDF that does *text->date*:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880489/12811606).
(given by another user, didn't test it)

**UDF**s need to be enabled in `cassandra.yaml` (`enable_user_defined_functions`);

**PS** [Documentation for UDFs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateFunction.html#:%7E:text=Creates%20custom%20function%20that%20execute,UDF%20scope%20is%20keyspace%2Dwide)

**Warning**:`dateOf()` is deprecated;

Hope this answers your question and works for what you need.
Cheers.