# How to convert a value of date type to text in Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

I have a Cassandra table with following structure -

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries_s (
   prop_name text PRIMARY KEY,
   description text,
   value text
);
```

Now I need to insert a property in this table whose value will be current date in text format. I have created the following CQL, but it gives me the following error -

```
 INSERT INTO timeseries_s (prop_name, description, value) VALUES ('xyz', 'abc', TODATE(now())));
```

**Error** - SyntaxException: line 1:168 mismatched input ')' expecting EOF (...'abc', TODATE(now()))[)]...)

Thereafter, I tried below -

```
 INSERT INTO timeseries_s (prop_name, description, value) VALUES ('xyz', 'Migration for DSE started at this time', CAST(TODATE(now()) AS TEXT));
```

**Error** - SyntaxException: line 1:158 no viable alternative at input '(' (... VALUES ('xyz', 'abc', CAST

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of to solve this one purely on the Cassandra side, is with a user defined function.  First of all, you'll need to enable user defined functions in the `cassandra.yaml`:

```
enable_user_defined_functions: true
```

Once the node(s) has been restarted, I accomplished this by defining a function called `totext` in my `stackoverflow` keyspace, like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totext (input DATE)
             RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS TEXT
             LANGUAGE java AS 'return input.toString();';
```

With that function created, you can use it in your `INSERT` like this:

```
> INSERT INTO timeseries_s (prop_name, description, value)
VALUES ('xyz', 'Migration for DSE started at this time',
                     stackoverflow.totext(todate(now())));

> SELECT * FROM timeseries_s ;

 prop_name | description                            | value
-----------+----------------------------------------+------------
       xyz | Migration for DSE started at this time | 2020-09-03

(1 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

`TODATE` takes `column_name` as input. Also, `CAST` is used in `SELECT` statements only. Probably you can achieve this thing through program.